# Remove POS (part-of-speech) tag from every words in sentence with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string where every word has a POS ([part-of-speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech)) tag:

```
The/DT suburb/NN of/IN Saffron/NNP Park/NNP lay/VBD on/IN the/DT sunset/JJ side/NN of/IN London/NNP ,/, as/IN red/JJ and/CC ragged/VBD as/IN a/DT cloud/NN of/IN sunset/NN ./.
```

How can I remove every POS tag (i.e. `/DT`, `/NN`, `/IN`, ..., `/.`) at once with RegEx in C# code?

Comment: Added explanation of what POS is, fixed capitalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess by "at once" you mean using a single call to `Regex.Replace`. You can safely remove them with the following regex:

```
/(?:[.,]|\p{Lu}+\b)
```

In C# regex, you do not have to escape `/`.

In case you want to remove *any* punctuation after `/`, you can use:

```
/(?:\p{P}|\p{Lu}+\b)
```

You need to use `string.Empty` as a replacement string.

```
var input = "The/DT suburb/NN of/IN Saffron/NNP Park/NNP lay/VBD on/IN the/DT sunset/JJ side/NN of/IN London/NNP ,/, as/IN red/JJ and/CC ragged/VBD as/IN a/DT cloud/NN of/IN sunset/NN ./.";
var rgxx = new Regex(@"/(?:[.,]|\p{Lu}+\b)");
var result = rgxx.Replace(input, string.Empty);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Sir, thank you for your reminder. I've encounter a new problem: Its/PRP$ leg/NN is/VBZ injured/VBN ./. One of the tags consists of dollar sign. How should I modified the expression to get it removed as well?

Comment: A dollar sign should be escaped inside a regex pattern to match a literal `$` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```
\/[A-Z.,]*
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/109